# Operating with a Combobox in a DataGridView C#/Winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, model-view-controller, datagridview, combobox

I have to display a **DataGridView** with a **ComboBox** for the following object

```
public class Service
{
   public int ServiceId
   public string Description
   public ServiceLevel ServiceLevel
}
public class ServiceLevel
{
 public int LevelId
 public string LevelDescription
}
```

The ComboBox must display the Level Description and allow the user to change it, by choosing between the N-Service Levels available.
I know I have to load the DataGridView and the ValueList for the ComboBox, but I cannot understand how to work with it. Does C# figure out automagically how to display the values or I have to link the ServiceLevel class with the ComboBox in order to be able to detect the change of the ServiceLevel ComboBox? How do I detect the changes in the ComboBox to generate/trigger the change actions (in this case, a HTTP request to be sent to a back end)?
Thanks in advance for the assist.

*EDIT*:
Added Code details, as per @JohnG's request.
*EDIT 2*:
Clarified the ComboBox name.

```
//ChangeList is for tracking ServiceLevel Changes on the DGV
public class Change
{
    public Change (int service, int servicelevel)
    {
        Service = service;
        ServiceLevel = servicelevel;
    }
   public int Service {get;set;}
   public int ServiceLevel {get;set;}
}
List<Change> ChangeList = new List<Change>();
private void loadDGV()
{
    //Get Services Json from HTTP request
    //Deserialize Services Json into Datatable
    //Get ServiceLevels Json from HTTP request
    //Deserialize ServiceLevels Json into Datatable

    DGV_Services.DataSource = dtServices;

    //DGV_CBC_ServiceLevel is the ComboBox inside DGV_Services
    DGV_CBC_ServiceLevel.DataSource = dtServiceLevels;
    DGV_CBC_ServiceLevel.DisplayMember = "LevelDescription";
    DGV_CBC_ServiceLevel.ValueMember = "LevelId";
}
private void DGV_Services_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
  ChangeList.Add( new Change(DGV_Services.CurrentRow.Cells["ServiceID"].Value), Convert.ToInt32(DGV_Services.CurrentRow.Cells["ServiceLevel"].Value)));
}

public void Save_Click (object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   foreach (Change item in ChangeList)
   {
    //Send HTTP POST request
   }
}
```

Comment: The ComboBox has a `DisplayMember` (what is presented) and a `ValueMember` (the underlying associated *Value*). When a selection is made in the ComboBox, the value associated with the Property set in `ValueMember` is evaluated.

Comment: Does the ValueMember get paired automagically with the object's Id? Do I have to declare/force the link between them?

Comment: If that's the actual model you're using, you'll have to replace Fields with Properties and normalize it (have an explicit `LevelId` Property in the main class). Or handle complex databindings *manually*.

Comment: What have you tried? From what little is here, I assume the grid is bound to a `List` of `Service` objects? If this is the case, then you will want to add a property to the `Service` Class that returns and sets the `ServiceLevel.LevelID`. The grid will not get the `ServiceLevel.LevelID` for you and this would be needed for the combo box columns `DataPropertyName`. Again, this assumes that the grid is bound to a `List` of `Service` objects.

Comment: @JohnG, I added code details (sanitized for your sanity)

Comment: You code is confusing in a sense that there are several different things named `ServiceLevel`? … The `DataGridViewComboBoxColumn` is named `ServiceLevel` ?... In the `Service` Class `ServiceLevel` is named `ServiceLevel`? From what I can see the `ServiceLevel` combo box column is not “bound” to any particular column in the grids data source. This is what the columns `DataPropertyName` is for... You want to point it to the proper column in the grids data source.

Comment: Also, it is unclear what the `Tables` schema is and what the purpose of the `Service` Class and `ServiceLevel` classes are used for. The code appears to be binding the grid and combo box column to `DataTable`s …? … where do the Classes come into play here?

Comment: @JohnG, The `Classes` are the representation of the DB Objects(Tables) stored into the `DataTables` , as in each `Row` in a `DataTable` is an instance of the `Class`. From what I understand, I need to add `DGV_CBC_ServiceLevel.DataPropertyName = dtService.ServiceLevel.Id` . Is that it?

Comment: Hmmm.... What columns are in the `Service` table? Does it have two (2) columns for the `ServiceLevel` Class? One for the Id and description? I am just not following what is displayed in the `ServiceLevel` column of the `Service` table. What Does the `Service` `DataTable` schema look like?

Comment: The `Service` table in the DB has a FK, `Service.ServiceLevel_Id` that is linked to `ServiceLevel` table field `LevelId`; the `ServiceLevel` table contains two fields, `Id` & `Description`.

Comment: IF ... _"The Service table in the DB has a FK, Service.ServiceLevel_Id that is linked to ServiceLevel table field LevelId"_ ... is true... THEN ... set the combo box columns `DataPropertyName` to "ServiceLevel_Id" ... I am assuming that `ServiceLevel_Id` IS a column in the `Service` table. This is still unclear "what columns" are in the service table after you get the data from the DB!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243264/discussion-between-johng-and-theo-bracco).

Comment: Let me see if I can clarify some of this. In reference to your comment that … _”… as in each Row in a DataTable is an instance of the Class”_ … ? … technically this is NOT true. A row in a `DataTable` is NOT an instance of a Class object… it is a `DataRow` and the `DataTable` has a collection of rows and columns. On the other hand, … a `List of <Service>` objects IS a collection of instantiated `Service` objects.

Comment: When you started your question, the only posted code was the code for the two Classes `Service` and `ServiceLevel`. This gives the impression that you are using a `List` of `Service` objects as a `DataSource` to the grid. After you posted more code, this revealed that instead of using a `List<Service>` as a `DataSource` to the grid, the code is using a `DataTable` … ? …

Comment: I have asked numerous times… what columns/fields are in the `Service` `DataTable`. You commented that … _”The Service table in the DB has a FK, Service.ServiceLevel_Id that is linked to ServiceLevel table field LevelId; the ServiceLevel table contains two fields, Id & Description.”_ … ? … this is NOT what I was asking.

Comment: Your comment describes how the data is organized IN the DB. I am asking what column/fields are in the `DataTable` that is returned from the DB query to get the “Service” table. This does not automatically/necessarily mean that the `Service.ServiceLevelID` is IN that table. That is why I asked what columns/fields are in the table. You can either show what columns are in the table and possibly the query that get the `Service` table from the DB. Sorry if I am missing something. Good Luck.